# Display image if checkbox checked AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I'm new at learning AngularJS and what I'm trying is to display an image if a checkbox is checked.

```
<body ng-app="imgApp" ng-controller="imgCNTRL">

<li class="stay-item" name="hotel" id="hotel1">
            <h2>Hotel Grande Bretagne</h2>
            <img src="https://www.fivestaralliance.com/files/fivestaralliance.com/field/image/nodes/2009/10181/10181_0_hotelgrandebretagne_fsa-g.jpg">
            <p class="img__description">
                Facilities
                <br><br>
                2 swimming pools
                <br>
                Free WiFi
                <br>
                Parking
                <br>
                Spa / Sallon
                <br>
                Bar
                <br>
            </p>
            <br><br>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="reserv" name="reserv">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="reserv">Reservation</label>
            </div>
        </li>
```

My code so far is this:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('imgApp', []);
        app.controller('imgCNTRL', function($scope){
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[name=reserv1]').click(function(){
                alert('ok');
                $scope.img1 = "https://t-cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/max1024x768/328010584.jpg?k=f8243c30e30a6671e3a618ed132f42d10bccd185b464caec8e7bbcb82915d837&o=&hp=1";
            });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

What I want to achieve is, If I click the button with the id="reserv", this image would be displayed([image](https://t-cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/max1024x768/328010584.jpg?k=f8243c30e30a6671e3a618ed132f42d10bccd185b464caec8e7bbcb82915d837&o=&hp=1)). Is there any convenient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an *ng-model="reserv_chk"* to your checkbox and an *ng-show="reserv_chk"* to your img:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-edison-uue0ti?file=/index.html